# md-nav-item is missing ink bar on first load

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

md-nav-item is missing ink bar on first load.  then even if i click on it, it won't show. although the md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" is working since i can see it when i try to log to console the value of currentNavItem, it's printing "Item1"

[image]

Then when I try to click on "Item2" then click "Item1", then the ink bar appears.

[image]

Here's my css:

```
  .md-nav-bar md-nav-ink-bar {
    background: black;
    height: 1px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `md-selected` directive with an integer value works for me on `md-tabs`

```
<md-tabs md-selected="0" ... >
```

or maybe `md-selected-nav-item="0"` works for you in this case.